# Rashi Shemos 14:4 seems to contradict later experience in the Midbar

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, moshe-rabbeinu, beshalach, golden-calf-egel

Rashi says in Parshas Beshalach [Shemos 14:4](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9875#showrashi=true&v=4), sv ויעשו כן:

> [This is stated] to tell their praise, that they obeyed Moshe and did
>   not say, “How will we draw near to our enemies [by returning in the
>   direction of Egypt]? We have to escape.” Instead they said, “All we
>   have are the words of moshe the son of Amram.” [I.e., we have no other
>   plan to follow, only the words of the son of Amram.]

If it's true that they only listen to the words of [Moshe] the son of Amram, then why later on do they do the *chate hagel* (the sin of the golden calf) or any of the other sins the jews did in the desert?

Comment: If you're going to use someone's translation, there are legal issues with not saying where you got it from. I linked to your source (which anyways, IMO, always improves a question), fixed up your title (which was very unclear, and could have applied to just about any Rashi in Chumash or Gemara) and made some other small edits. If I've done anything you don't like, you can always [edit] yourself to fix.

Comment: I think you might ask a stronger question from the waters of Marah or some other story than from the חטא העגל; Moshe wasn't around by the *chate hagel*.

Comment: @Shokhet I was just giving an example i will edit it thank for pointing it out!

Comment: No problem; glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rashi is saying that in this instance they followed Moshe even though it didn't make sense. That is why the verse emphasizes that they did it - they did it despite the fact that it wasn't reasonable.

They didn't always behave that way, in fact right afterwards ([v. 11](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9875#v=11&showrashi=true)) in this very story.

Comment: If I understood the question correctly (and I think I did), this doesn't really answer the question; it's more restating it in the form of a statement.

Comment: @Shokhet, the question presumes that they *always* listened to Ben Amram, and Rashi means to say this. The answer is that Rashi is *only* saying that they listened in this instance and that the words of the verse come to emphasize that in *this* instance only. In other instances the verse doesn't say that they blindly followed, and they didn't.